# what is the best way to extract filled data from a static form?

Tags: scala, parsing, text-processing, text-parsing

I have some federal pdf forms with filled data init. Lets say for example [i765](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-765.pdf) and I have the data of this form available in a text format, with duly filled in details. How can I extract the data from this form with minimum parsing. Lets say how can write a script that identifies "difference" , which in itself is nothing but the filled information.

For eg: if a line contains..

SSN: (Whitespace)   and the actual filled in form has SSN: ABC!@#456

so the filled in information is nothing but ABC!@#456 which just a difference between the strings . Is there a known approach that i can follow. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: If you have text versions of both the blank form and filled-in form, try this in a shell: `diff BlankFile.txt FileWithData.txt`. Does that give what you need? If so, write a Scala program that iterates over the two text files and compares the data. If you have difficulties, show your work here and we'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about Linux Tools then you could try various solutions , like:

```
$ join -t"=" -a1 -o 0,2.2 <(sort emptyform) <(sort filledform)  # "=" is used as delimiter
```

Or even awk without sorting requirements:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if ($1 in a) {print;delete a[$1]}} \
END{print "\n Missing fields:";for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' empty filled
```

Testing:

```
cat <<EOF >empty
Name=""
Surname=""
Age=""
Address=""
Kids=""
Married=""
EOF

cat <<EOF >filled
Name="George"
Surname="Vasiliou"
Age="42"
Address="Europe"
EOF
join -t"=" -a1 -o 0,2.2 <(sort empty) <(sort filled)
#Output:
Address="Europe"
Age="42"
Kids=
Married=
Name="George"
Surname="Vasiliou"
```

awk output

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if ($1 in a) {print;delete a[$1]}} \
END{print "\nnot completed fields:";for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' empty filled

Name="George"
Surname="Vasiliou"
Age="42"
Address="Europe"

not completed fields:
Married=""
Kids=""
```

Especially in awk if you remove the print from `{if ($1 in a) {print;delete a[$1]}}` the END section will print out for you only the missing fields.

Another alternative with a nice visual interface is with diff utility:

```
$ diff -y <(sort empty) <(sort filled)

Address=""                            | Address="Europe" 
Age=""                                | Age="42"  
Kids=""                               | Name="George" 
Married=""                            | Surname="Vasiliou"                                              
Name=""                               <  
Surname=""                            <
```

Comment: updated. Let me know if above solutions are suitable.